# Test with Twilio Connect App

Tags: testing, twilio

Is there a way to test with the Twilio Connect App?  You can only authorize an app that is not a free trial account by logging in which authorizes the production account.  You do not get a chance to authorize a test account.  Because of that any calls you try to make with the Connect App test credentials fail because your test credentials are not authorized to use the other production account.  Does anyone know of any workarounds for this?

Comment: OP - did you find any solutions?

Comment: @MordechayS no I did not.  What you said below is true but not for Connect App.  The account has to be authorized through the Connect App and Connect App will not authorize trial accounts.  When it authorizes a non trial account, it creates a sub account for that account only viewed through their API.  The Api does not return the Test Account Id for the sub account so there is no way to figure out what the Test Account SID would be.  What you say below is all true except for through the Connect App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no you cannot.  The account has to be authorized through the Connect App and Connect App will not authorize trial accounts. When it authorizes a non trial account, it creates a sub account for that account only viewed through their API. The Api does not return the Test Account Id for the sub account so there is no way to figure out what the Test Account SID would be.

Because the account you want to "test" with has to be a production account you will be charged.  I talked to Twilio Support about this and they acknowledged what I ran into and gave me a credit to my account to play around with.  I would not expect that for everyone but hopefully this will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Public Disclosure:**
*Never have I tried any of the two suggestions given by Twillio, neither have I tried to actually implement them in my account.*

**Option 1: Create A New Account - Stay In Trial:**

You said:

> "...You can only authorize an app that is not a free trial account by
>   logging in which authorizes the production account"

This negates a fully-written suggestion in `Twillio`'s site. From `Twillio`'s [help-center](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183808-Why-aren-t-my-test-credentials-working-):

> [Test credentials](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136147-Where-are-my-test-credentials-) only provide a way for you to "pretend" sending a
>   message or making a phone call ... If you are looking for end-to-end
>   testing without being charged, we recommend that you create a separate
>   Twilio account and stay in the trial mode to take advantage of the
>   trial credits.

**Option 2: Using Your Test Credentials In Production Enviroment:**

You said:

> "...Because of that any calls you try to make with the Connect App test
>   credentials fail because your [test credentials](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136147-Where-are-my-test-credentials-) are not authorized to
>   use the other production account"

This seems strange, as in production, your test credentials **will work** - although just for specific services. From `Twillio`'s [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials):

> Supported Resources
>
> Your [test credentials](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136147-Where-are-my-test-credentials-) can currently be used to interact with the
>   following three resources:
>
> - Buying phone numbers:
>
>   POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers
> - Sending SMS messages:
>
>   POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/Messages
> - Making calls:
>
>   POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/{TestAccountSid}/Calls
>
> Requests to any other resource with test credentials will receive a 403 Forbidden
>   response. In the future, we may enable these resources for testing as
>   well.

Hope this helps a bit. Nevertheless, tell us what you came up with in your different trial and errors.

Good luck!